# count in between values in a column on condition say I need to count for only specific value and group them by another column using python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following input

Input:

```
Bus Fare Startcity
56  98   sathy
95  85   sathy
98  95   chennai
85  92   chennai
56  75   chennai
56  83   chennai
```

I have to **count** it by fare >=90 and fare<=98 and groupby "Startcity"

Output 1:

```
Fare Startcity 
1    Sathy 
2    Chennai
```

Also to calculate **average**if fare >=90 and fare<=98 and groupby "Startcity"

Output 2:

```
Fare   Startcity
98     Sathy 
93.5   Chennai
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want count number of rows per condition per groups create boolean mask by [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ge.html) (`<=`) and count `True` values by `sum`:

```
df1 = df['Fare'].ge(90).groupby(df['Startcity']).sum().astype(int).reset_index()
print (df1)
  Startcity  Fare
0   chennai     2
1     sathy     1
```

---

If want check [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with filtering use:

```
df = df[df['Fare'].between(90, 98)].groupby('Startcity')['Fare'].mean().reset_index()
print (df)
  Startcity  Fare
0   chennai  93.5
1     sathy  98.0
```

Or if need also `0` for non matched groups:

```
df3=df.groupby('Startcity')['Fare'].apply(lambda x: x[x.between(90, 98)].mean()).reset_index()
print (df3)
  Startcity  Fare
0   chennai  93.5
1     sathy  98.0
```

Comment: how to do it for between values?

Comment: also to calculate mean value

Comment: @YogeshSP - Can you explain more?

Comment: please check the question now edited it clearly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @YogeshSP - Do you need `mean` ? I try it, but get `0` in both solutions.

Comment: Yes I "Mean" it wont be zero check the table Fare   Startcity
98     Sathy 
93.5   Chennai

Comment: @YogeshSP - Sorry, give me a sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176857/discussion-between-yogesh-s-p-and-jezrael).